# How can I calculate the day of the week of a date in ruby?

Tags: ruby, date

How can I calculate the day of the week of a date in Ruby? For example, October 28 of 2010 is = Thursday

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I have used this because I hated to go to the Date docs to look up the strftime syntax, not finding it there and having to remember it is in the Time docs.

```
require 'date'

class Date
  def dayname
     DAYNAMES[self.wday]
  end

  def abbr_dayname
    ABBR_DAYNAMES[self.wday]
  end
end

today = Date.today

puts today.dayname
puts today.abbr_dayname
```

Comment: looks like the Time class also has a #wday method, FWIW.

Comment: Distilling steenslag to one line that directly answers the poster: use `Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES[Date.today.wday]`.  (You do have to include the Date library before you can use it: `require Date`.)  Options: to show full day names instead of just first three letters, use `DAYNAMES` instead of `ABBR_DAYNAMES`.

Comment: is there any way to get a number from 0..6 without converting it yourself?

Comment: I think that probably mway's solution below is the better way to go here—no sense in re-defining functionality that already exists (i.e. dateObj.strftime('%A')), right?

Answer (score 75):

Take a look at the [Date class reference](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.5/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime).  Once you have a date object, you can simply do `dateObj.strftime('%A')` for the full day, or `dateObj.strftime('%a')` for the abbreviated day.  You can also use `dateObj.wday` for the integer value of the day of the week, and use it as you see fit.

Comment: How would you localize this, say if you were using Rails?

Comment: `#wday` should be the best answer for this.

Answer (score 33):

```
time = Time.at(time)    # Convert number of seconds into Time object.
puts time.wday    # => 0: Day of week: 0 is Sunday
```

Comment: Also there is `Time#cwday` for getting dates on 1-7 range. Also these methods are nowadays (Ruby 2.3 at least) present at Date class too.

Comment: `Time` has no `cwday`, but `Date` has.

Answer (score 31):

```
Date.today.strftime("%A")
=> "Wednesday"

Date.today.strftime("%A").downcase  
=> "wednesday"
```

Answer (score 10):

Quick, dirty and localization-friendly:

```
days = {0 => "Sunday",
1 => "Monday", 
2 => "Tuesday",
3 => "Wednesday",
4 => "Thursday",
5 => "Friday",
6 => "Saturday"}

puts "It's #{days[Time.now.wday]}"
```

Answer (score 7):

Works out of the box with ruby without requiring:

```
Time.now.strftime("%A").downcase #=> "thursday"
```

Answer (score 5):

As @mway said, you can use date.strftime("%A") on any Date object to get the day of the week.

If you're lucky `Date.parse` might get you from String to day of the week in one go:

```
def weekday(date_string)
  Date.parse(date_string).strftime("%A")
end
```

This works for your test case:

```
weekday("October 28 of 2010") #=> "Thursday"
```

Answer (score 5):

Say i have `date = Time.now.to_date` 
then `date.strftime("%A")` will print name for the day of the week and to have just the number for the day of the week write `date.wday`.

Answer (score 2):

In your time object, use the property .wday to get the number that corresponds with the day of the week, e.g.  If .wday returns 0, then your date is Sunday, 1 Monday, etc.

Answer (score 1):

From 2022:

`DateTime.current.thursday?`

Based on https://apidock.com/ruby/Date/tuesday%3F

And

```rb
> DateTime.current.is_a? Date
 => true
```

Comment: while it might be obvious to some what your answer is, could you maybe extend your answer with a bit of explanation and a reference to the docs or library you are using or referencing?

Answer (score 0):

basically the same answer as Andreas

```rb
days = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday']
today_is = days[Time.now.wday]

if today_is == 'tuesday'
  ## ...
end
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use `#name_of_week_day` method like this:

```
Date.today.name_of_week_day
```