# Ruby, check if date is a weekend?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a DailyQuote model in my rails application which has a **date** and **price** for a stock. Data in the database has been captured for this model including weekends. The weekend price values have been set as 0.

I want to change all the weekend prices for Saturday and Sunday to whatever the price was on Friday. What is the best way to do this in Ruby? To identify if a date falls on a Sat or Sun and change its value to the Fri of that weekend?

Comment: also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044574/how-calculate-the-day-of-the-week-of-a-date-in-ruby

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
require 'date'
today = Date.today
ask_price_for = (today.wday == 6) ? today - 1 : (today.wday == 0) ? today - 2 : today
```

or

```
require 'date'
today = Date.today
ask_price_for = (today.saturday?) ? today - 1 : (today.sunday?) ? today - 2 : today
```

`ask_price_for` now holds a date for which you would want to ask the price for.

Getting the actual price which is corresponding to you date depends on your Model and your ORM-Library (i.e. ActiveRecord).

Comment: If you use rails, @tsundoku's answer is better

Comment: In which way is it better? because it uses Time instead of Date? (which doesn't have anything to do with rails). `saturday?` and `sunday?` are used here as well.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't attentive enough

Comment: You can execute `Date.today.on_weekend?` for this.

Answer (score 56):

[TFM](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html) shows an interesting way to identifying the day of the week:

```
t = Time.now
t.saturday?    #=> returns a boolean value
t.sunday?      #=> returns a boolean value
```

Comment: Actually Rails provides the `on_weekend?` method. `Time.now.on_weekend? #=> true if saturday or sunday` Also, `on_weekday?` does the opposite.

Answer (score 26):

### The simplest approach:

```
today = Date.today

if today.saturday? || today.sunday? 
  puts "Today is a weekend!"
end
```

---

You can also do this for any other day of the week.  Ruby is fantastic and offers a lot of cool methods like this.  I suggest when you get stumped take a look at what's available to the class by running `.methods` on it.  So if you run `Date.today.methods` you will see these available.

Answer (score 15):

```
class Time
  def is_weekend?
    [0, 6, 7].include?(wday)
  end
end

time = Time.new

puts "Current Time : " + time.inspect
puts time.is_weekend?
```

Comment: Sundays can be 7 or 0. I'd probably change that to `[0, 6, 7].include?(wday)`.

Comment: This answer is quite accurate. Left me wonder where do I add code to extend a Ruby class.

Comment: like I did in my answer, by using the keyword class you create a class but also you extend or overwite methods in the class if it is allready known to Ruby. In this case is_weekend? is a non existend method in the normal class Time so the method extends the original class from that point in code

Answer (score 9):

since rails v5:

```
Date.current.on_weekend?
```

References:

- [api-doc](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/DateAndTime/Calculations/on_weekend%3F)
- [rails docu](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.3.4/classes/DateAndTime/Calculations.html#method-i-on_weekend-3F)

Answer (score 5):

Date.today.instance_eval { saturday? || sunday? }

Comment: I use the same method for weekend and holidays
`Date.today.instance_eval { saturday? || sunday? || holiday?(:it) }`

Answer (score 1):

Checking of weekend days (Saturday and Sunday) in the range of two dates in ruby

```
 weekend_days = [0,6]
 if (start_date.to_date..end_date.to_date).to_a.select {|k| weekend_days.include?(k.wday)}.present?
    # you code
 end
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.