# How to get day of a ruby Date Object

Tags: ruby, date, datetime

Say I have created a Data object like this.

```
semester_start_date = Date.new(2013,1,15)
```

Now how I can find if `semester_start_date.day == 'Thursday'` or any other day for that matter?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044574/how-calculate-the-day-of-the-week-of-a-date-in-ruby

Comment: I need another vote to close this question - but stay on SO - because it is possible that someone come to this question via search engine query and forwarded to right answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using 1.9, you should be able to do this:

```
require 'date'

d = Date.new(2013,1,15)
d.thursday? #=> false
d.wday #=> 2
Date::DAYNAMES[d.wday] #=> "Tuesday"
d.tuesday? #=> true
```

I'm assuming you aren't actually looking for a date object that's the same as the string "Thursday"