# Rails last day of last week bug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I'm trying to get the last day of last week.

Today is:

```
d = Date.today
=> Sun, 22 Nov 2015

d.at_end_of_week
=> Sun, 22 Nov 2015

d.at_end_of_week.last_week
=> Mon, 09 Nov 2015
```

The last command should return Mon, 15 Nov 2015, no?

This also returns the same FYI:

```
Date.today.at_end_of_week.last_week
 => Mon, 09 Nov 2015
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are seeing is correct. Note that `last_week` is an alias of `prev_week` which takes an optional parameter that defaults to `Date.begining_of_week` (`:monday`)

Resulting in trying to find the date in the previous week but from the past monday.

If instead you call `Date.today.at_end_of_week.last_week :sunday`. For what you try to accomplish you need a way to replace `:sunday` with something based on today's date. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044574/how-calculate-the-day-of-the-week-of-a-date-in-ruby) but I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Date.today.last_week.at_end_of_week
```